# Saying "It's the principle of the matter"

Tags: word-choice

How does one say "it's the principle of the thing", in particular for when giving feedback.

For example, it's not the 1$ over change but the principle of the matter.
(as in the one dollar doesn't really matter but the principle of being overcharged is what is at issue).

I took a look at ALC and it gave me 原則{げんそく} and 基礎{きそ} but these don't really seem to fit the definition very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

主義{しゅぎ} is a principle or rule. I think this would apply to your personal principles or values.

So for the "it is the principle that matters", you could respond:

> 私の主義ですから。
>
> Since it is my principle.

Alternatively:

> 主義が重要ですから。
>
> Since it is the principle that is important.

For a less literal translation, [Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%89%A9%E3%81%AE%E9%81%93%E7%90%86) gives the meaning of 物{もの}の道{どう}理{り} as the "principle of the thing". So the most fitting phrase would be:

> 物の道理ですから。
>
> It is the principle of the thing.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, this answer, please add a comment for why

Comment: + 1 for a well-researched and proper answer. If I may add, in actual conversation I'd translate this to something like、「問題は1ドルの過剰請求ではなく、過剰請求自体がされていることだ」(The problem is not being overcharged by $1, but by being overcharged itself.) Good luck on getting the reason for the downvote though. I myself have experienced it a few times in my short time here. People here sometimes don't give consideration to the time and effort exerted in giving a proper answer. IMO giving a reason for a downvote should be made a rule, as without one, it's very discouraging to give an answer.

Comment: @DXV ah, 自体 also is a really good word for the situation as well! Thanks! (I think it deserves in be in an answer rather than a comment so others can see it in the future)

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't count on it any time soon. In my experience, this occurs more on the Japanese site than other SE sites. I fear this discourages new contributors which I think has been raised on the meta. Still I try to help where I can.

Comment: @TomKelly yes I just read the meta. I'm one of those discouraged to answer. Thanks but sorry paullb.